# How to press & long press the "back" key with a terminal command?

Tags: terminal, buttons, scripts

We manage Zebra Mobile computing units running on Android 6.0 Marshmallow through an MDM. For some reason, the MDM interface doesn't show the Android buttons at the bottom of the screen (back, home, menu, etc).

I was able to find the script for the home screen on this site.

Is there a way to send the script for other buttons as well?

Comment: Have you tried KeyEvents? [ADB Shell Input Events](//stackoverflow.com/a/28969112)

Comment: `adb shell input keyevent 4` this should trigger the back key